How to export table from Apache Superset chart to excel with conditional formatting?
I applied conditional formatting to the values in the table - I colored the values in a column with different colors, but after exporting to Excel format, the conditional formatting was missing in the Excel document.
I searched the entire internet and found nothing except for commercial versions of superset, where this feature is implemented.
